# How to toggle and remember div in localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, css, local-storage

I want to alter the color of a div based on a click. 
Then I want it to remember that color when refreshed. 
At last I want to be able to click on the same div and change back it's color to the original color.

I've managed to create the first and second statement.

```html
<div class="deurbody">
<div class="nooddeurknop btn-secondmenu">5</div>
<div class="nooddeurknop btn-secondmenu">4</div>
<div class="nooddeurknop btn-secondmenu">3</div>
<div class="nooddeurknop btn-secondmenu">2</div>
<div class="nooddeurknop btn-secondmenu">1</div>
</div>
```

```
$(".btn-secondmenu").css('background-color', localStorage.getItem(".btn-secondmenu"));
$(".btn-secondmenu").click(function () {
$(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
var status = $(".btn-secondmenu").css('background-color');
localStorage.setItem(".btn-secondmenu", status);
});
```

```css
.deurbody {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 80px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 60px);
    grid-row-gap: 7px;
    height:100%;

} 

.nooddeurknop:nth-child(odd) {
    display:grid;
    grid-column: 1 / 3; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color:white;
    background: #FF5552;
    height:auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 50px;

}

.nooddeurknop:nth-of-type(even) {
    display:grid;
    grid-column: 1 / 3; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color:white;
    background: #E64C49;
    height:auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 50px;

}

.nooddeurknop:nth-last-child(1) {
    display:grid;
    grid-column: 1 / 3; 
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color:#E64C49;
    background: #272727;
    height:auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 50px;

}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pyhrfq4z/

I want to be able to change back the grey div into a red div.

I tried the toggle attribute of jquery but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: When do you want to get color back? on page refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it by toggling a class and remembering the toggle. So:

```
.btn-secondmenu.special-color {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

then

```
var className = "special-color";
$(".btn-secondmenu").toggleClass(className, localStorage.getItem(".btn-secondmenu") === "Y");
$(".btn-secondmenu").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass(className);
    if ($this.hasClass(className)) {
        localStorage.setItem(".btn-secondmenu", "Y");
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(".btn-secondmenu");
    }
});
```

or

```
var className = "special-color";
$(".btn-secondmenu").toggleClass(className, localStorage.getItem(".btn-secondmenu") === "Y");
$(".btn-secondmenu").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass(className);
    localStorage.setItem(".btn-secondmenu", $this.hasClass(className) ? "Y" : "N");
});
```

depending on whether you want to have the local storage key when you haven't set the special color.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/xq47gdcu/1/)

---

**Note:** Your original code applies the same local storage key to all of the divs on page load, so I left it that way. If you want them toggled independently, you have a couple of choices:

- Use a separate key for each div, or
- Use a single key containing flags for the divs

I tend to prefer to have a few local storage entries rather than lots of them, so I'd tend toward the latter:

```
var className = "special-color";
var storageName = "colorToggleState";
var colorToggleState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageName)) || {};
$(".btn-secondmenu").addClass(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.index(); // Or use some other more reliable identification of the button
    if (colorToggleState[index]) {
        return className;
    }
});
$(".btn-secondmenu").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.index(); // Or use some other way of identifying the button
    colorToggleState[index] = !colorToggleState[index]; // `undefined` is falsy, so this works just fine
    $this.toggleClass(className, colorToggleState[index]);
    localStorage.setItem(storageName, JSON.stringify(colorToggleState));
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/xq47gdcu/2/)

Comment: I want them to be toggled independently indeed! the seperate key is the "Y" in this matter?

Comment: @Sauvage - Added an example for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code. Your buttons were almost duplicate code. Try to create one base class and append different classes or in this case `child` selectors.

In my opinion I don't like jQuery. So i rewrote it in vanilla javascript.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('deurbody__knop')).map(knop => {
 console.log(localStorage.getItem(knop.id));
 if (localStorage.getItem(knop.id) == 'true') knop.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    
 knop.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if (knop.style.backgroundColor == 'grey'){
     knop.removeAttribute('style');
      localStorage.setItem(knop.id, false);
    }
    else {
     knop.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
      localStorage.setItem(knop.id, true);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.deurbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 15em;
}

.deurbody__knop {
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.deurbody__knop:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ff5552;
}

.deurbody__knop:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #E64C49;
}

.deurbody__knop:last-child {
  background-color: #272727;
  color: #E64C49;
}
```

```html
<div class="deurbody">
  <div class="deurbody__knop" id="deurbody__knop-5">5</div>
  <div class="deurbody__knop" id="deurbody__knop-4">4</div>
  <div class="deurbody__knop" id="deurbody__knop-3">3</div>
  <div class="deurbody__knop" id="deurbody__knop-2">2</div>
  <div class="deurbody__knop" id="deurbody__knop-1">1</div>
</div>
```